# Angular-file-upload and Rails with Carrierwave

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I've been trying to workout upload photo using angular-file-upload and Rails with the carrierwave .. I got an error `Converting circular structure to JSON`, I already google the problem it seems I didn't get the idea how to remove that I error. I just followed the tutorial in https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/examples/simple/index.html.

Angular

```
$scope.sp = { serviceprovider: {
              avatar: { name: $scope.uploader = new FileUploader() }
            },
             categories: [],
            clearances: [2] 
            };


$scope.registerProvider = function registerProvider () {
                console.log($scope.sp);
                $http.post('/serviceproviders/new_serviceprovider/', $scope.sp )
                .success ( function onLink ( response) {
                    location.href = "index";
                })
                .error ( function onLink ( response ) {
                    console.log(response)
                });
            }
```

HTML

```
<section ng-controller="RegisterServiceProviderCtrl">
<!-- multistep form -->
      <form id="msform" ng-submit="registerProvider()" novalidate>
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
          <li class="active">Authentication</li>
          <li>Personal Information</li>
          <li>Professional Skill</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
         <!--  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3> -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <center><div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                  <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
                  <div>
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="uploader"/><%#= f.file_field :avatar %></span>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                  </div>
                </div></center>
            </div>
          </div>
..... code
```